# Three table join with max value in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have three tables as follows (there are additional fields, but irrelevant here):

```
Class Application():
  id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  name: str = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=true, index=True, nullable=False)

  appmappings: List[AppEnvMapping] = db.orm.relationship("AppEnvMapping", order_by=AppEnvMapping.deploy_date.desc(), back_populates='application', lazy='joined')
```

```
Class Environment():
  id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  name: str = db.Column(db.String(10), unique=true, index=True, nullable=False)

  envmappings: List[AppEnvMapping] = db.orm.relationship("AppEnvMapping", order_by=AppEnvMapping.deploy_date.desc(), back_populates='environment', lazy='joined')
```

```
Class AppEnvMapping():
  id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
  app_id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('applications.id'), index=True, nullable=False)
  env_id: int = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('environments.id'), index=True, nullable=False)
  deploy_date: datetime.datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, nullable=False)

  application = db.orm.relationship('Application', back_populates='appmappings', lazy='joined')
  environment = db.orm.relationship('Environment', back_populates='appmappings', lazy='joined')
```

Simple pretty far, and I'm able to join them and get a full list of everything with relative ease.  However, what I really need is to send a query that returns only the rows with the latest `deploy_date` for each `app_id`, `env_id` combo.  So, for instance, if the `AppEnvMapping` table had the following data:

```
id | app_id | env_id | deploy_date
1  | 1      | 1      | 01-01-2021
2  | 1      | 1      | 02-01-2021
3  | 1      | 2      | 01-10-2021
4  | 2      | 1      | 02-04-2021
5  | 2      | 1      | 04-15-2021
```

Then the query should return these rows:

```
id | app_id | env_id | deploy_date
2  | 1      | 1      | 02-01-2021
3  | 1      | 2      | 01-10-2021
5  | 2      | 1      | 04-15-2021
```

The kicker here being that I need the corresponding Application and Environment data as well.  I can do this with SQL, but I can't seem to figure out the syntax to do this in SQLAlchemy.  The following SQL gives me the data I want:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, ae.env_id, e.name, ae.daploy_date
  FROM applications AS a
  INNER JOIN appenvmappings AS ae
    ON ae.app_id = a.id
  INNER_JOIN (SELECT id, max(deploy_date) max_date
                FROM appenvmappings
                GROUP_BY app_id, env_id) maxlist
    ON ae.id = maxlist.ie
      AND ae.deploy_date = maxlist.max_date
  INNER_JOIN environments AS e
    ON ae.env_id = e.id
```

The closest I've gotten in SQLAlchemy is this:

```
maxlist = session.query(AppEnvMapping, func.max(AppEnvMApping.deploy_date).label('maxdate'). \
          group_by(AppEnvMapping.app_id, AppEnvMapping.env_id). \
          subquery('maxlist')

applist = session.query(Application). \
          join(AppEnvMapping).\
          join(maxlist, and_(AppEnvMapping.id == maxlist.c.id, AppEnvMapping.deploy_date == maxlist.c.maxdate).\
          join(Environment).\
          all()
```

But what I get is a full list as if I joined the tables without the subselect at all.  I *suspect* it's because I add in `join(AppEnvMapping)`, but if I don't add that join, the query fails with an error that the `appenvmapping.id` column doesn't exist, despite the relationship in the underlying classes.  I've tried using the relationship names, but I can't seem to figure out what syntax to use, or even if that's feasible.

I'd love any hints anyone can provide on how to resolve this.  Thanks in advance!